# JPA and JPQL LIMIT when used in subquery

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, hql, limit

First I would like to point that I know how I could do this in SQL by using the LIMIT but because JPQL doesn't allow LIMIT keyword hence my question:

I have a JPQL query that return places and their linked tags:

```
List<Object[]> p = entityManager.createQuery("
SELECT p, t.tagName
FROM Place p LEFT JOIN .... ...
```

for example this could return
place1 | tag1
place1 | tag2
place1 | tag3
place2 | tag1
place2 | tag4

Now.. I obviously cannot simply return the full database places.. and i cannot simply put a LIMIT at the end of the quest because im returning tags so I don't how how many row etc..

In SQL I would do something like this

```
SELECT p.name, t.tag_name FROM ... WHERE p.idPlace IN (SELECT p.idPlace FROM ... WHERE... LIMTI 10);
```

I would make a sub query and use the LIMIT in there to only select the place I want.

But because JPQL doesn't allow LIMIT, for now what I'm doing is a 2nd Database call to retrieve my desired placeIds and using the entityManager setMaxResult. to limit. and then I feed these Ids into the other query.

Could someone more experienced with JPA tell me if this a good practice? Is there  a other way of doing the things without having to make 2 separated database call ?

Ps: the reason i'm selecting t.tagName directly in the query is because  the collection PlaceTag (inside the Place entity) is LAZILY initialised and if I access it in java it will trigger an extra database call.. I DID i have tried to use JOIN FETCH like this:

```
List<Place> places = entityManager.createQuery("" +
                "SELECT p FROM Place p " +
                "JOIN FETCH p.PlaceTag pt " +
                "JOIN FETCH pt.tag t").setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
```

So I could do something like this in java (without triggering a new database when accessing p.getPlaceTag() and getTag()

```
for (Place p : places) {
  for (PlaceTag pt: p.getPlaceTag())
      System.out.println(pt.getTag().getTagName());
}
```

But I get this error about the query:

> Query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched
>   association was not present in the select list

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 String query =   "SELECT p FROM Place p "
                  + "JOIN p.PlaceTag pt " 
                  + "JOIN pt.tag t";
 List<Place> places = entityManager.createQuery(query)
                      .setMaxResults(10)
                      .setFirstResult((pageNumber-1) * pageSize)
                      .getResultList();
```